# Error in list question not able to sort and print

Tags: python

Im new to python programming please help
Im trying to find the element at the second last position of a list.

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
      n = int(input())
      arr =list(map(int, input().split()))
      z=[]
      z=arr.sort()
      print(z[-2])
```

im getting this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/submission/20220829/07/41/hackerrank-67f9dc4719fec8f34c675c684c0aef6b/code/Solution.py", line 6, in 
print(z[-2])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

even if i try printing just z it outputs 'None'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` sorts a list in place an returns `None`. For this usecase, you can use `sorted`:

```py
z = sorted(arr)
```